# Remove encoding using PHP

Tags: php, encode

I have the following text:

```
We%27re%20proud%20to%20introduce%20the%20Amazing
```

I'd like to remove the encoding using PHP, but using `html_entity_decode()` does not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
echo urldecode('We%27re%20proud%20to%20introduce%20the%20Amazing');
```

This is an url_ecoded string. Use [`urldecode`](http://php.net/urldecode)

Answer (score 7):

This encoding is called [Percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) or URL encoding. In PHP you have [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode), [`rawurldecode`](http://php.net/rawurldecode) for “raw” URL encoding as well as the [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) and [`urldecode`](http://php.net/urldecode) for the slightly different encoding that is used in the query (rather known as [*application/x-www-form-urlencoded*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) where the space is encoded with `+` instead of `%20`).

In your case the “raw” URL encoding is used. So try `rawurldecode` to decode it:

```
rawurldecode('We%27re%20proud%20to%20introduce%20the%20Amazing')
```

Comment: +1 for rawurlencode/decode, but "rather known when using" means what?

Answer (score 1):

%27 and %20 are URL encoded entities.

You'll want to use use [urldecode()](http://us.php.net/urldecode) to decode this.  [urlencode()](http://us.php.net/urlencode) exists as well for encoding URL parameters.