# i want to remove %20 from the url in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my page url

`http://myaliveidea.com/news/news/readmore/56/%20When%20Harry%20and%20Sally%20met%20New%20York%20City`

but i want my page url like this
`http://myaliveidea.com/news/news/readmore/59/When-Harry-and-Sally-met-New-York- City`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove encoding using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418771/remove-encoding-using-php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: ?!??! So, are you generating those URLs yourself in the first place? Then replace spaces by dashes, obviously. Otherwise, you'll have to give more context what exactly the problem is in doing what you want to do.

Comment: use [urldecode]http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Use "str_replace" for this.. it'll solve your problem..

Comment: Are you using code igniter?,if so try to remove the spaces from the last parameter with "-" using "str_replace"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution of this question is

```
  <?php
                    $url = str_replace(' ','-',$sport['title']);
                    $url = str_replace(":",'',$url);
                    $url = str_replace("'",'',$url);    
                ?>


<a href="<?php echo base_url().'news/readmore/'.$sport['id']."/".urlencode($url);?>"><?php echo $sport_top['title'];?></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use    `urldecode();`

```
$url = urldecode($url);
```

then replace `spaces(' ') by - using str_replace();`

Comment: may use str_replace("%20","",$url);