# remove %20 from url in codeigniter site

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter site, I am generating the name of country and search on another page. My url is: (http://localhost/turkish/Travels/list_flight/Almaty)
its working fine but when the country name have two words like "Abu Dhabi" it makes the url (http://localhost/turkish/Travels/list_flight/Abu%20Dhabi) which cannot search because in the database it is written as "Abu Dhabi".

I think it is resolved in htaccess file. any one help me please.

Thanks

Comment: have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632600/i-want-to-remove-20-from-the-url-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your country name using `GET` method 
Example :

```
http://localhost/turkish/Travels/list_flight?country=<?php echo $countryname ?>
```

and get you country name in controller using `$this->input->get('country')`

this will not give you any `%20` in your country name.