# a tag with php adds %20 even without spaces

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

```
<a class="links" href="buying.php?link=<?php echo $urlname?>">Gekauft</a>
```

This line is a link to this url

```
http://127.0.0.1/fridge/buying.php?%20item=Milch"
```

when it really should be this

```
http://127.0.0.1/fridge/buying.php?item=Milch
```

As you can see it adds %20 i dont get why. Any help appreciated

Comment: URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

Comment: Perhaps it's something to do when the `link` variable is converted to an `item` variable - ie your php and urls don't match

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632600/i-want-to-remove-20-from-the-url-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try something like this to remove white spaces:

```
<a class="links" href="buying.php?link=<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $urlname) ?>">Gekauft</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In URL encoding `%20` is equal to `space`. I am assuming that in your URL you have space and it is automatically has been encoded to `%20`, deleting it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use trim function to remove space from the string.

If you want to replace space with + character use str_replace function.

Answer (score 0):

Use urldecode for this. [urlencode](http://php.net/urldecode)

```
 $url = "http://127.0.0.1/fridge/buying.php?%20item=Milch";
 echo urldecode($url);
```